# How to run py file using the terminal and write on file

Tags: python, file, terminal, raspberry-pi

I'm relatively new to python and wanted to test the basic functions of python like writing and reading from files. Using this code it worked flawlessly:

```
text = "hello there"
file = open("testfile.txt", "w")
file.write(text)
file.close()
```

Next I wanted to run it using the terminal. I wrote
*python3 [fileDir]/testing.py* and pressed enter but unfortunately I wasn't able to get any text written on testfile.txt.
I know, it might be a silly beginners' question but please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: Did you get any output at all? Try throwing a `print("running")` in there for some feedback.

Comment: Not possible. Your code either didn't run at all, or the file is in another directory

Answer (score 0):

use `cat testfile.txt`
and it output "hello there" in terminal. Due to No newline, It will ouput in a line with teminal prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine your code is in the directory `./test-dir`. Thus, your file tree relative to the current directory is:

```
.
└── test-dir
    └── testing.py

1 directory, 1 file
```

If you run `python test-dir/testing.py`, your *current working directory* is `.` (here, `.` denotes the directory you are currently in, the parent directory of `test-dir`). Thus, the path `somefile.txt` will be in `.`, not in `./test-dir`.

Running:

```
python test-dir/testing.py
```

changes your directory structure to:

```
.
├── test-dir
│   └── testing.py
└── testfile.txt

1 directory, 2 files
```

In general, all paths in your code will be interpreted as relative to the directory *in which you run the Python command* (i.e. `.`), not the directory in which the Python source files are (i.e. `./test-dir`).

Answer (score 0):

First, thank you guys for your answers!

Today, I tried it once again and got it finally printing "hello there" onto the file.
I had some text written in the `testfile.txt`, so i deleted the whole file and tried it again. Then, with no text written in the file, it worked perfectly.

So firstly I thought the file has to be empty to write something in it. But then I tried it once again with text in it and it functioned as expected.

Anyways, now it's running flawlessly and thank you for wasting your time!